# split is not a function on array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have just started programming with javascript. I am trying to work with arrays and I don't understand why I am getting a split is not a function error, when I try to split the content of the array like in the following code.

```
var addressArray=[[]];
/*
some code to pass values to the addressArray 

*/

var values=addressArray[i].split(/ ,+/);
```

the error is occuring where I am spliting

Comment: There's no `.split()` function for arrays. There is a String `.split()` however. It's hard to know what it is you want to do without actually seeing the stuff in your array.

Comment: in the array there phrase like: 1 housenumber street  city, 2 hause number street city

Comment: Incidentally, that regex matches "exactly one space followed by one or more commas", which seems an odd thing to look for. But maybe it makes sense in your context.

Comment: yes there are commas and after each comma a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot split an array itself - `split()` is used to split a string *into* an array. I suspect you're attempting to split a string that is within an array, in which case you should be careful to index the string correctly. Looking at your declaration of `addressArray`:

```
var addressArray=[[]];
```

You seem to have nested arrays, in which case you will need to use two indices to refer to a string within an array, which is itself within `addressArray`; for example, `addressArray[i][j].split(/ ,+/)`.